# Replacing files in a folder with another file with a dos-batch

Tags: command, dos, batch-file

Is there any example on DOS Batch - Find and Replace command for files?

I need to find all files with some exact name in a folder (and its sub folders) and replace tham all (one by one for ex) with another known file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like "rename" do what you want?
RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.

- Dew

Comment: No. 
I need to find all files with some exact name in a folder (and its sub folders) and replace tham all (one by one for ex) with another known file

Answer (score 0):

for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir c:\myfolder\myoriginalfilename.txt /s /b') do ((del "%a") & copy MyNewFilename.txt "%~dpa")